# Next.js API routes all return "Interval Server Error" in production, but all the routes work in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, next.js, production

Whenever I go to any API route in my Next.js app in production it returns a 500 "Internal Server Error" but in development, all of them work completely fine and show/return what I expect them to.

[image: another example of the error]

[image: the error]

I am deploying with an AWS Ec2 instance.

the code is available here: https://github.com/123om123/NFT-Marketplace

These are all my API routes.

[image]

The [...auth0].js creates the following routes:
`/api/auth/login`,
`/api/auth/logout`,
`/api/auth/callback`, and
`/api/auth/me`

If I try to access the "find_account" API route like the following:

```
  let findAccount = async function () {
    await fetch("/api/find_account", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        DBUrl: DBUrl,
        user_id: user.sub,
      }),
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        await response.json().then((result) => {
          accountData = result;
          if (accountData.data.allAccounts.nodes[0].addresses !== null) {
            setAddressList(accountData.data.allAccounts.nodes[0].addresses[0].split(","));
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };
```

which handles requests like the following:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  req.body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  fetch(req.body.DBUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `query MyQuery {
        allAccounts(condition: {userId:"${req.body.user_id}"}) {
          nodes {
            addresses
          }
        }
      }`,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      response.json().then((response) => {
        res.status(200).send(response);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}
```

it works fine and returns the response from the graphql API in development, but in production it shows the above error.

The problem seems to be that the API routes aren't even created and are therefore inaccessible. All the API routes worked a few weeks ago, but now they seem to have stopped working.

Comment: Try and post the code that applies to this issue so we can debug, not just a link to your entire project. See [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @about14sheep I'm not sure what code I could use to reproduce this, since it works in development and not in production

Comment: show how you are calling the api on the frontend and then how you are handling the request on the backend

Comment: @about14sheep AFAIK next.js API routes are automatically handled and you access them with "/api/routeName" added to the end of the url

Comment: Some error is occurring in your API routes in production. Either the requests you make from the client are not sending the right things, or something's wrong in the API routes themselves. Check the API routes logs on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves The problem is that the API routes don't seem to exist in production, they exist in development, but as soon as I run it in production they aren’t even created it seems

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer, it helped me solve a bug similar to yours. In my case when vercel was deploying my PR branch I was getting a 500 Internal Error. Once I merge the PR into main and vercel does a fresh deployment, I was now getting a 504 gateway error. The answer below helped me find out why.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774331/12775824